# Inserting images to user-specific collections mongoDB via PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to upload images submitted by users into a collect in the mongoDB. I want each collection to be a unique folder that represents that user.

I'm also using php to help achieve form submission of other data. This is the code I have at the moment:

```php
    include "../../mongoconnect.php"; //creates mongoconnect variable
    $db = $mongoconnect->mydb;
    $collection = $db->$_SESSION['username'];
    $document = array( 
        "name" => $_FILES['file']['name'],
        "image_data" => new MongoDB\BSON\Binary(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['name']), 
                      MongoDB\BSON\Binary::TYPE_GENERIC) 
                 ); 
    $collection->insert($document);
```

I'm very new to mongoDB and I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. I also read about GRIDFS but I couldn't find anything that suggests it supports user specific storage.

If anyone could suggest improvements etc. that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this: *I want each collection to be a unique folder that represents that user*?

Comment: @codemonkey So I wish to have a collection (table) for each user. This is because when the user uplaods an image, it can be stored in the user collection (e.g. zorko). So all uplaoded images by the user will be in one location, and separate from other user uploads

Comment: I hate dispensing architectural advice but creating a collection for each user sounds like a bit of an overkill. I am curious as to why not have them all live in one collection where they represent a separate document? You can just as well store those images in their respective docs.

Comment: @codemonkey thanks, im here for advice. So one collection that stores all the documents should work? Only issue is what if two users have the same image and name, would that cause anything?

Comment: Each document in a collection will have a unique `_id` (think of a row in a relational DB). No issues will arise from having sames images or names. A document is like a row except that it can store subdocuments which makes it super flexible. So yes, create a collection called `User` and then insert a document for each user you have.

Comment: @codemonkey appreciate thanks, so above, would that be the structure you would go? I.e. ``name``, and ``image_data``. The collection will be called ``Users`` and not per user like i thought before

Comment: Depends on what other info you want to store I suppose. I would do something like `name`, `email`, `date_created`, `image_data`, etc. This will show you how to create that collection: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.createcollection.php

Comment: @codemonkey appreciate it, i would upvote for your efforts and time but I can't